# How would you focus the cursor in a Quill Editor that resides in a Bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, quill

I understand that something like the following will start the Quill editor and focus on it...

```
const quill = new Quill("#quill-editor", {
    theme: 'snow'
})
let text ="Lorem ipsum dol"
quill.insertText(0, text);
quill.focus();
```

But I've got the Quill editor in a Bootstrap 3 Modal and the focus call does not work.

I've tried focusing on the DIV directly...that doesn't work either.

Seems a shame to have such a nice editor and not be able to help a user out by setting them up to type by placing focus!

Would there be another way to make it happen? CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    quill.focus();
})
```